# Limit curl memory usage

Tags: c, curl

I have linux daemon which uses constant Curl handler. Curl caches same connections, domains etc.. Thus memory usage grows dramatically. Is it possible to limit somehow curl memory usage?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: using libcurl-openssl instead of libcurl-gnutls significantly reduced memory usage

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to dump the response to a file instead of keeping it in memory.

```
curl {{command and arguments}} > curl_response.data
```